# Python script called by Ajax, executed by Django server

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I'm new here and had a problem recently. I have a Django based site and I need to execute a python script from javascript. I've found some answers how can I achive this:

*test.py*

```
def main():
return "Hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

*test.html*

```
<div class="calc_range"></div>
```

*test.js*

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/static/devices/test.py",
    success: function(o) {
        $(".calc_range").html(o);
    }
});
```

It looks simple but it's not working. In `.calc_range` div I just get plain python text instead of "Hello":

```
def main(): return "Hello" if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

I read that it is server problem but right now I'm just using Django development server (runserver). I'd like it to work in both development and production (Apache server) enviroment. Could anyone help me solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do it like this.

1) Add a new url in urls.py

2) Add a view for this url in views.py

3) write a function that will do your operations and call it in the view and return the values as json.

4) Call this url in ajax.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how ajax is supposed to work. You need to define a url in your `urls.py` file with a corresponding view in `views.py`.

Within that view you will call your function. to do something more substantial than returning 'hello', preferrably encoded in json.

Ajax will then call that specific url.

I would recommend you to go through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) if you feel uncomfortable with what I am proposing above.

Regarding deploying to Apache, it is a large topic which mainly is covered in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/) as well.